# Getting information about exchange server?

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I have an exchange server 2013 in my office. I want to find all the information about exchange server that i found using exchange management shell commands. I wants to find data like below.

> Server name, number of mailboxes, number of mail contacts, information store, storage group, recently created and deleted mailboxes, information about all the emailflow through exchange server, information about senders, receivers and many more information that i find from exchange server.

programmatically. I want to find this information programmatically from a geographical distance using C#. I have window 7 on my machine through which, i wants to do this. I am trying this using remote power shell with C#.
For example, i have an exchange management shell commands i.e.

```
Get-mailbox -resultsize unlimited -filter {$_.forwardingaddress -ne $null} | select name, userprincipalname
```

after executing the above cmdlets using exchange management shell,i have get some data, i wants to get similar information programmatically using C#.

My code snippet

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation; 
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
   public Form1()
   {
        InitializeComponent();
   }
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     string schemaURI = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange";
     Uri connectTo = new Uri("https://<serverIP>/powershell/");
     string strpassword = "password";   
     System.Security.SecureString securePassword = new System.Security.SecureString();
     foreach (char c in strpassword)
     {
         securePassword.AppendChar(c);
     }
     PSCredential credential = new PSCredential("Administrator", securePassword);
     WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(connectTo,schemaURI, credential);
     connectionInfo.MaximumConnectionRedirectionCount = 5;
     connectionInfo.SkipCACheck = true;
     connectionInfo.SkipCNCheck = true;
     try
     {
        Runspace remoteRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
        remoteRunspace.Open();
        var command = new Command("Get-mailbox");
        command.Parameters.Add("resultsize", "unlimited");
        command.Parameters.Add("Filter", "{forwardingaddress -ne $null}");
        var pipeline = remoteRunspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.Add(command);
        var results = pipeline.Invoke();    
        foreach (PSObject item in results)
        {                                                                                          
            PSPropertyInfo pinfo = (PSPropertyInfo)item.Properties["Name"];
            PSPropertyInfo prop = (PSPropertyInfo)item.Properties["userprincipalname"];
            //prop = item.Properties["Name"];
            if (pinfo != null)
            {
                  MessageBox.Show(pinfo.Value.ToString());
            }
            if (prop != null)
            {
                  MessageBox.Show(prop.Value.ToString());
            }
         }
         remoteRunspace.Dispose();
        }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
      }            
    }
  }
}
```

The line:

```
   remoteRunspace.Open();
```

Produce an exception given below:

> *Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. The WinRM client tried to
>   use Negotiate authentication mechanism, but the destination computer
>   (IP:443) returned an 'access denied' error. Change the configuration
>   to allow Negotiate authentication mechanism to be used or specify one
>   of the authentication mechanisms supported by the server. To use
>   Kerberos, specify the local computer name as the remote destination.
>   Also verify that the client computer and the destination computer are
>   joined to a domain. To use Basic, specify the local computer name as
>   the remote destination, specify Basic authentication and provide user
>   name and password. Possible authentication mechanisms reported by
>   server: For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting
>   Help topic*

How can i fix this type of exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the below given path on your server about which you wants to get the above information.

```
Start Menu -> Administrative tools -> iis manager -> Sites -> default web site -> powershell
```

Then select IIS Authentication in /powershell home and after opening the authentication there are six authentication listed as below

```
Anonymous authentication "disabled"
Asp.net impersonation    "disabled"
Basic authentication     "disabled"
Digest authentication    "disabled"
Forms authentication     "disabled"
Windows authentication   "disabled"
```

Now enabled the last one authentication i.e. windows authentication.After enabling windows authentication they look like below

```
Anonymous authentication "disabled"
Asp.net impersonation    "disabled"
Basic authentication     "disabled"
Digest authentication    "disabled"
Forms authentication     "disabled"
Windows authentication   "enabled"
```

After that run your code, and u got the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the AuthenticationMechanism on the WSManConnectionInfo object your using to match how you have configured your Exchange Server. If your using https then you should set it to Basic eg

```
connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
```

Otherwise if you still have the default config on your Exchange Server you can use Kerberos and http so change which is what's used in the MSDN samples http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335083(v=exchg.150).aspx (Make sure you use the FQDN not the IP)

```
Uri connectTo = new Uri("http://<FQDN>/powershell/");
```

and then use

```
connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
```

Cheers
Glen

Comment: I am set the AuthenticationMechanism on the WSManConnectionInfo object, and i also replace the server IP by FQDN, but still i am getting an exception i.e.








**Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request because the server name cannot be resolved. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.**

Comment: That error is pointing to you not being able to resolve the FQDN your trying to use. You should be able to ping whatever servername your using if you can't this will never work. Have you tried just using Powershell to connect from the console ? if you work out what auth/server setting work in the console you should be able to easily move these into your code.

Comment: I have added FQDN properly & i tried Powershell to connect to console but i'm unable to connect as same error accoured.

Comment: It sounds like you have an underlying network issue you should be able to ping and resolve the FQDN ?. If you can't get the console to work your code will never work you might want to try the debugging steps in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351136(v=exchg.141).aspx